# "square" scatter for matplotlib ax

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I have this code for scatterplot:

```
for row_output in results:
    for current_result in row_output:
        mat = np.stack([current_result.x, current_result.y]).T
        colors = current_result.rgb_values
        size = [100] * colors.shape[0]
        ax.scatter(x=mat[:, 0],
                   y=mat[:, 1],
                   c=colors,
                   s=size,
                   alpha=opacity)
        
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

but i am getting this uneven result:
[image]

is there a way for me to use this `set_aspect('equal')`  property, but make the plot in the same length?

(I saw that there is `plt.axis('square')` option, but i cound not figure how to use it in an existing ax)

Comment: The [samples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-axis-equal-demo-py) in the official reference will help you solve your problem.

Comment: `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'data')` should do it...

Comment: Thanks. 
```ax.axis("equal")``` solved it for me